# Retrieve a GeoCoder Near method from another table's latitude and longitude

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-geocoder

I have a function that takes all the results from the model and returns and gets passed to `.near()` method to get the closest results. Thing is that I do not store the latitude and longitude on that table. I use the Profile's lat/lng to display results

My method is looking for the `Datings` table lat/lng for the `.near()` method and I need it to look at the `Profiles` lat/lng instead.

Here is what I have so far.

```
@results = Dating.all
      .where("datings.open_to_dating = true")
      .where("datings.identity = ?", @category )
      .where("datings.deleted_at is null")
      .joins("INNER JOIN users on datings.user_id = users.id")
      .joins("INNER JOIN profiles on datings.user_id = profiles.user_id")

distance = 75
@results = filter_search_results_by_distance(@results, lat, lng, distance)




def filter_search_results_by_distance(results, lat, lng, distance)

results = results
          .joins("INNER JOIN users on datings.user_id = users.id")
          .joins("INNER JOIN profiles on datings.user_id = profiles.user_id")
          .near([lat, lng], distance, units: :km) # 20 Miles
          .order("distance")
end
```

I'm trying to do a join and possibly do a `profiles.near([lat,lng]`.

Comment: What result are you expecting?  What result are you getting instead?

Comment: @WayneConrad I am getting "ERROR: column datings.latitude does not exist" thats because I am running a .near() on the Dating model. Although I want it to run using the joined profiles model (which has a lat/lng)